# Error with my assignment

Tags: c++, string, oop

I had one assignment from my prof., but after coding, I got over 40 errors but don't know why :(

My assignment: 
" Build CHAR and STRING class (STRING is a string of CHAR) with these samples:

```
class CHAR
{
private:
 char content;
/* Insert more codes here */
};
class STRING
{
private:
CHAR * content;
int length;
/* Insert more codes here */
};
```

and then test with this main function:

```
int main()
{
CHAR c1, c2('c');
STRING s1, s2("s2"), s3('a'), s4(c1);
s1.expand(c2).expand('a').expand(s2).expand("abc");//s1: "cas2abc"
s1.remove(c2).remove('d');//remove all character c2 in s1 -- s1: "as2ab"
s1.input();//insert new string from keyboard
cout<<s1.getContent();// export content of s1
cout<<c1.getContent();// export content of c1
return 0;
}
```

My code link here: https://bugs.vn/10670
Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?  What was the *first* error you got?  Can you reduce the size of your program and still reproduce the error?  We want to see the entire question here - not some link to a different site.  Have you seen the help section "How to ask"?

Comment: Yes, I have seen. But I think my source code were not short to post :( So I put in site. My question is: I got too many errors with my assginment. I have asked my friend before, but we still find no solution to my problem.

Comment: The bugs seem to be in main(). You can't call functions you have not defined.

Comment: My main function is just stop at expand('a'), but when I run the code in my school's computor, some errors appear.

Answer (score 2):

Check compiler errors!

Your `STRING` class does not have methods: `remove`, `input`, `getContent`. You can not call methods which you have not defined.

This will compile and run.

```
// CHAR.h
#include <iostream>
// STRING.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h> //sg7

using namespace std;

class CHAR
{
private:
    char content;
public:
    CHAR();
    CHAR(char);
    char GetContent();
    void SetContent(char);
};


class STRING
{
private:
    CHAR * content;
    int length;
public:
    STRING();
    STRING(const char*);
    STRING(char);
    STRING(const CHAR&);
    STRING& expand(const CHAR&);
    ~STRING();
};

// CHAR.cpp
// #include "CHAR.h"

CHAR::CHAR()
{
    this->content = '\0';
}

CHAR::CHAR(char)
{
    this->content = 'c';
}

char CHAR::GetContent()
{
    return content;
}

void CHAR::SetContent(char C)
{
    content = C;
}

// STRING.cpp

//#include "STRING.h"
//#include "CHAR.h"

STRING::STRING()
{
    this->content = NULL;
    this->length = 0;
}

STRING::STRING(const char *c)
{
    this->length = strlen(c);
    this->content = new CHAR[this->length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
    {
        this->content[i] = CHAR(c[i]);
    }
}

STRING::STRING(char c)
{
    this->length = 1;
    this->content = new CHAR[1];
    this->content[0] = CHAR(c);
}

STRING::STRING(const CHAR &c)
{
    this->length = 1;
    this->content = new CHAR[1];
    this->content[0] = c; //.SetContent(c.GetContent());
}

STRING& STRING::expand(const CHAR &c)
{

    CHAR *new_content = new CHAR[this->length + 1]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
    {
        new_content[i] = this->content[i]; 
    }
    new_content[this->length] = c; 
    if(this->content!=NULL)
    {
        delete[] this->content;
    }
    this->content = new_content;
    this->length++;
    return *this;
}

STRING::~STRING()
{
    if (this->content != NULL)
        delete[]this->content;
}

int main()
{
    CHAR c1, c2('c');
    STRING s1, s2("s2"), s3('a'), s4(c1);

    s1.expand('a');

    return 0;
}
```